# Downloading every source from website in browser

Tags: networking, browser

when browsing (with a browser) on a website with images on it, the images are being logged in the `Network`-Tab in the browser's devtools. Now, when being on some websites, the images are often linked as `blob`s, like `blob:https://google.com/image` or something. Is it possible to automatically download every `blob` in the `Network`-Tab by the browser? Like just a few button presses and 200 images are automatically being downloaded?